# wireless ath9k suddenly stopped working on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, atheros, ath9k

Following is the result of wireless-info script:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 31 May 2018 12:21 IST +0530

Booted last: 31 May 2018 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 10 Jan 2018 20:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-127-generic #153-Ubuntu SMP Sat May 19 10:58:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [8086:15b8] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [1043:8672]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:abcd] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Limited. Device [10cf:16a8]

03:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller [1b21:1242]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 006 Device 002: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 03f0:2f4a Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 03f0:094a Hewlett-Packard Optical Mouse [672662-001]
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

eeepc_wmi              16384  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 eeepc_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
ath9k                 147456  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              479232  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              737280  1 ath9k
cfg80211              565248  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
mxm_wmi                16384  0
wmi                    20480  2 mxm_wmi,asus_wmi
video                  40960  2 i915_bpo,asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          inet addr:192.168.0.105  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e15c:7462:4f65:e036/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3674 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2847 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3883593 (3.8 MB)  TX bytes:367643 (367.6 KB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:f7300000-f7320000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:497 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:497 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:43961 (43.9 KB)  TX bytes:43961 (43.9 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s31f6
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s31f6
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s31f6

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       816     1  0 11:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s31f6
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.2.6-k
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0.8-4
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/enp0s31f6
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp0s31f6
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Ethernet connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       bd5b5fc1-d82f-46f4-8b70-124c1c679b20
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   bd5b5fc1-d82f-46f4-8b70-124c1c679b20 | Ethernet connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.105/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1527755965
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 7200
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.0.105
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.0.1 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::e15c:7462:4f65:e036/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp0s31f6  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s31f6  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[ath9k]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-127-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     D578DE67B7E1EB3760B717B
depends:        mac80211,ath9k_hw,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-127-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           led_active_high:Invert LED polarity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
parm:           use_chanctx:Enable channel context for concurrency (int)

[ath9k_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-127-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     5E13CACC8C4252BB4B57367
depends:        ath9k_hw,cfg80211,ath
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-127-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 

[ath9k_hw]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-127-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     19C5721EB199C107B73269F
depends:        ath
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-127-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-127-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     65C8D1B35656DB13F597E87
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-127-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-127-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     6F6591120B0B257B6E5E85B
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-127-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-127-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     AF52F2B944842498D5E951F
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-127-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath9k]
blink: 0
bt_ant_diversity: 0
btcoex_enable: 0
led_active_high: -1
nohwcrypt: 1
ps_enable: 0
use_chanctx: 0

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf]
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   87.441558] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   87.441564] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[   87.759852] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Down
[   87.763483] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   89.477550] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   89.477563] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[   89.477634] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s31f6: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Jgi.png)

---

**EDIT:** I updated my ASUS H170 Pro Gaming motherboard to the latest BIOS and the problem got fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please notice the very unusual device ID for your device: 168c:abcd.

When we search for this exact ID, we find this: https://www.mail-archive.com/ath9k-devel@lists.ath9k.org/msg10055.html

> some time ago there was a thread "Sparklan WPEA-121N AR9382 168c:abcd"
>   about the issue that the mentioned device was erroneously reported as
>   device ID 0xabcd. There were EEPROM issues assumed and BIOS issues
>   reported that could cause this effect (by resetting the PCI bus at
>   system power on)

And this: https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/168c/abcd

> ID abcd is used by Atheros devices when not properly initialized by
>   BIOS.

I suggest that you fully update the BIOS on your computer. I also suggest that you be certain that the card is fully and firmly seated in the PCI slot.

I believe this is a hardware issue and not an Ubuntu operating system or driver issue.

Comment: I updated my ASUS H170 Pro Gaming motherboard to the latest BIOS and the problem got fixed.